# Parsing date error on lower android version in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, date-parsing

```
 var birthDate= DateFormat('yyyy/M/dd').parse(tempBirthDate);
 print(birthDate);
 String dtStringBday = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(birthDate);
 
 //print result: 1967-08-16 00:00:00.000
```

Hi I'm using this code to parse and format my date. But I'm having this error `Error: FormatException: Trying to read yyyy from at position 0` on my android version 6.0.1 SamsungJ7 but not in my Samsung A8 android version 7.1.1. Does android version affects the date parsing? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong way, but you are very close
check this example

example:

```
//before we show the date we need to parse it then show it in a format Month 2 , 2020

     Container(
    child: Text(new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.parse(productInfo["createdAt"]))),
               ),

// in my example this is time variable: productInfo["createdAt"]
```

[DateTime class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)